# Calculate relative positions in strings

Tags: text-processing

Sample input file:

```
#name   complete(cs)    len(cs) simple(ss)  len(ss) position(ss)
NAME1   A0AAA000AAA00A  14      AAAAAAAA    8        4,6
NAME2   AAAA0AA00000A   13      AAAAAAA     7        7
```

Let's say I'm interested in knowing the corresponding position in the complete string (cs) of some letters of the simplified string(ss), given in the position(ss) column. 
*Note: in the simple string(ss), only letters are allowed. In the complete string, every character's allowed.*

In this exemple, it would return:

Sample output file:

```
#name   complete(cs)    len(cs) simple(ss)  len(ss) pos(ss) pos(cs)
NAME1   A0AAA000AAA00A  14      AAAAAAAA    8        4,6    5,10
NAME2   AAAA0AA00000A   13      AAAAAAA     7        7      13
```

I'm currently building this file using python, but I'm sure there is an easy Unix way out.

Comment: Can you make it clearer? What is relationship between `pos(ss)` and `pos(cs)`?

Comment: `pos(ss)` are positions of the `simple(ss)` string. I'd like to find their equivalent positions `pos(cs)` in the `complete(cs)` string. For exemple, if I take the first row, position `4` of the `simple(ss)` is actually position `5` in the `complete(ss)` . That's because `complete(cs)` contains a `0` that causes a shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -anle '
    print "$_ position(cs)" and next if /^#/;
    printf "%s",$_;
    for $pos_ss (split ",",$F[5]) {
        $char = substr($F[3],$pos_ss-1,1);
        @cs = split //,$F[1];
        @cs_idx = grep {$cs[$_] eq $char} 0..$#cs;
        push @res,++$cs_idx[$pos_ss-1];
    }
    printf "%14s\n", join ",",@res;
    @res=();
' file
#name   complete(cs)    len(cs) simple(ss)  len(ss) position(ss) position(cs)
NAME1   A0AAA000AAA00A  14      AAAAAAAA    8        4,6          5,10
NAME2   AAAA0AA00000A   13      AAAAAAA     7        7            13
```

**How does it work**

- First two lines print the original entry.
- `for $pos_ss (split ",",$F[5])`: we split field 6, get each index wanted in simple string.
- `$char = substr($F[3],$pos_ss-1,1)`: get the character at given index in simple string.
- `@cs = split //,$F[1]`: we get all characters in complete string, save them to an array.
- `@cs_idx = grep {$cs[$_] eq $char} 0..$#cs`: get all indexs in array `@cs`, which value equal `$char`.
- `push @res,++$cs_idx[$pos_ss-1]`: save the index we wanted to array `@res`.
- Last two lines just print the result we got and empty `@res` array for next use.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a beginning with bash operators and hardcoded info. It is quite auto-explanatory:

```
#!/bin/bash

word="A0AAA000AAA00A"
required=(4 6)
match="A"
w=$word

# get the positions of $match in $word
while [ ! -z "$w" ]; do
    n=$(expr index "$w" $match)
    w=${w:$n}
    counter=$(( counter + n ))
#   echo "position $counter. now w=$w"
    pos+=($counter)
done

echo "All positions: ${pos[@]}"

# print the position of $match in $word on positions given by $required
for i in "${required[@]}"
do
    echo "position $i: ${pos[i-1]}"
done
```

A generic case can be done with some kind of `while read; do... done < file`, fetching the necessary columns.